# Formatting a string array in java

Tags: java, string, printing, formatting

I have a string array which has k elements. I want to print them out using System.out.format, but the issue is that I do not know k. So essentially, I want to use something like:
`System.out.format("%s %s ... k times", str1, str2, ... strk);`
(where k is a variable)

I was looking through the java documentation, but could not find a way to do this. Is there a simple way out?

Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps `Arrays.toString()` is probably what you are looking for.

Comment: Not really, the point is that I want to specify the number of characters that I want for each string. Something like %15s

Comment: @ashu: your explanation isn't making a lot of sense to me. Could you edit your post an give an example array + output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a loop:

```
for (String s : array) {
    System.out.print(String.format("%s ", s));
}
System.out.println();
```

Answer (score 62):

you can use

```
System.out.format("%s". Arrays.toString(your_array));
```

Comment: Wont this have the `[` and `]` contained within the string which we do not want?

Answer (score 9):

Java 8:

```
String formatted = Stream.of(arrayOfStrings)
    .collect(Collectors.joining(",","[","]"));

String formatted = Stream.of(arrayOfSomethingElse)
    .map(Object::toString)
    .collect(Collectors.joining(",","[","]"));
```

Answer (score 2):

```
for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    System.out.print("%s ", array[i]);
}
```

Comment: You'd say `array[i]`. I also would suggest use `array.length` instead `k`

Comment: I whipped that together too quick, thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for(String s : myArray){
    sb.append(s).append(" ");
}
sb.append(myArray.length).append(" times");
System.out.println(sb.toString());              // print the string
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you simply want to concatenate *k* strings with a space between each of the strings? You don't need `System.out.format` for that. You could simply create a loop to concatenate them together with a `StringBuilder`:

```
public String concatStrings(String... s) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    if (s.length > 0) {
        sb.append(s[0]);
        for (int i = 1; i < s.length; i++) {
            sb.append(' ').append(s[i]);
        }
    }

    return sb.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> I want to specify the number of characters that I want for each string. Something like %15s

That will only specify the padding for each `String`. If the `String` length is less than the value specified in the format specifier, then the full `String` is used. You could use [`substring`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int,%20int%29)

```
void displayArray(String[] str, int characters) {
    for (String s: str) {
        System.out.print(s.substring(0, Math.min(s.length(), characters)) + " ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That's typical **toolbox code** - code you often use and reuse, and best keep in a static-access utility class (such as `StringUtil`). Here's a generic function that works on all kinds of non-primitive arrays, and lets you specify the separator (space, comma, slash, whatever):

```
public static <T> void print (PrintStream out, String separator, T... elements) {
        for (int i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
            if (i > 0) {
                out.print(separator);
            }
            out.print(elements[i]);
        }
    }
```

Example Usage:

```
String[] s = {"A", "B", "C", "D", "E"};
Integer[] n = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}; //non-primitive
print(System.out, " ", s);
print(System.out, ", ", n);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `String.join()` to format your array to your desired result.

```
System.out.println(String.join(" ", array));
```

Comment: This is the most efficient actually